# how to subscribe to bumper topic on move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, roomba, roomba-500-series, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner at ROS and ROS navigation stack.

I have been using `roomba_500_series` and navigation stack (including `move_base` module). I would like to subscribe to `/bumper` topic in move_base. The topic type of /bumper is `roomba_500_series/Bumper`. I can already use bumper topic by using `kobuki_bumper2pc`. However I want to use the topic in `move_base` one way or another.

First of all, I would like to try to turn rommba left when the right bumper is true after publishing /cmd_vel. I modified `move_base.cpp` like below.

`move_base.cpp` (line: 902~) [link text](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/e538b4f4624c7f757d4868e5200ba8f8904a0d94/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L902)

```
//make sure that we send the velocity command to the base                             
 vel_pub_.publish(cmd_vel);      　     
//***modified part
 bump_sensor_sub_ = nh.subscribe("/bumper", 1000, &MoveBase::BumperSensorCB, this);  
 if (right_bumper==1){            
    publishZeroVelocity();
    while(right_bumper==1){
       cmd_vel.linear.x = 0.0;
       cmd_vel.linear.y = 0.0;
       cmd_vel.angular.z = 0.78;
       vel_pub_.publish(cmd_vel);

       bump_sensor_sub_ = nh.subscribe("/bumper", 1000, &MoveBase::BumperSensorCB, this);
    }
 }  //***
```

function `MoveBase::BumperSensorCB` which I made

```
void MoveBase::BumperSensorCB(const roomba_500_series::Bumper::ConstPtr& msg) 
  {
    left_bumper = msg->left.state;
    right_bumper = msg->right.state;
  }
```

`right_bumper` & `left_bumper` are boolean data type

```
bool right_bumper, left_bumper;
```

I modified move_base.cpp as noted above. However roomba doesn't work as I thought. It seems like `MoveBase` can't subscribe to `/bumper` topic now. Although, the cause might be `CMakeLists.txt` , I have no idea how to modify it to use `/bumper` topic from `roomba_500_series`.

Sorry that was such a long post and my poor English.

I would appreciate it if you could answer my question.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277767/how-to-subscribe-to-bumper-topic-on-move_base/) by [rostaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31338/rostaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-20**:
Why did you modify `move_base.cpp`? Modifying source code as you did is generally not a good idea. If/when you update this package your modification will be gone.

**Comment by [rostaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31338/rostaro/) on 2017-12-21**:
I am trying to create new `state_` [link text](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/8f5628d99e99620bcc6abc508852aee35b597982/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L857) in `MoveBase::executeCycle`.
When `/bumper`'s state is unavoidably true, I'd like to control roomba in new `state_`.

**Comment by [rostaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31338/rostaro/) on 2017-12-21**:
The modifying code above is to confirm whether it works or not on an experimental basis.
I am not a engineer, so I have no idea, it is good or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are subscribing to the same topic in a `while`.

You have to subscribe only once.

Since you are already subscribing to the node before the `while`, try to remove the  `bump_sensor_sub_ = nh.subscribe("/bumper", 1000, &MoveBase::BumperSensorCB, this);` that is inside the `while(right_bumper==1){}` and see if it works.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rostaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31338/rostaro/) on 2017-12-20**:
Thank you for answering my question and I`m sorry for the delay in my reply.

Actually, I am subscribing the same topic in a `while`.
My intention is to exit the `while` by updating bumper data.
Therefor, I am doing it.
Please excuse my lack of explanation.

**Comment by [rostaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31338/rostaro/) on 2017-12-20**:
In terms of this question that I have posted, I have already solved the problem.
The cause might be `CmakeLists.txt`.
I appreciate your understanding and cooperation.
Please excuse any mistakes in this letter.
Thank you.